# How do I create a custom pull source element that works with the gst1-java-core framework?

Tags: java, gstreamer

I am experimenting with the [gst1-java-core framework](https://github.com/gstreamer-java/gst1-java-core) which provides java bindings for the gstreamer framework.

I would like to figure out how to create a custom element such that java code can provide data on demand to downstream gstreamer elements (probably means providing pull pads).

I managed to implement a toy push element (which behaves kind of like a `filesrc`) with the following code fragments:

```
Element filesrc = ElementFactory.make("appsrc", "appsrc");
AppSrc as = (AppSrc) filesrc;
// this next bit runs in a separate thread
byte[] buffer = new byte[4<<10];
FileInputStream istr = new FileInputStream(tsfname);
while (true) {
    int n = istr.read(buffer);
    if (n<1)
        break;
    Buffer gBuffer = new Buffer(buffer.length);
    ByteBuffer b2 = gBuffer.map(true);
    b2.put(buffer, 0, n);
    System.out.println("sending "+n+" bytes into gstreamer");
    as.pushBuffer(gBuffer);
 }
```

But considering how quickly the loop completed I suspect that results in 55 megabytes of data piling up in a queue somewhere.  How would I create an `Element` that the gstreamer pipeline can pull from such that java code gets called to create or fill the `Buffer` only when the downstream elements need the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing and connecting a `NEED_DATA` object to your `AppSrc`. See [line 110 here](https://github.com/gstreamer-java/gst1-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/gstreamer/examples/AppSrcToAppSinkExample.java#L110) for an example. Basically, there is a callback function (`needData`) every time your pipeline needs more data. Here, you can call `as.pushBuffer(gBuffer)`. Also, if you do not have data to push, remember to either call `as.endOfStream()`, or push an empty `Buffer`, otherwise `needData` will never be called again until a buffer is pushed.